# Update parent model from fake Inline model in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

The Number model is fake model without table and i shouldn't save it. All i need is save all inlines Number.number as Message.receiver.
But save_model calls  first and after saving Message cals save Number which just pass. I need to acces parent Message model from Number inline model.
I tried to overload save_model() from NumberAdmin but wit no success.
I know what design is bad but it is legacy.

models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    receiver = models.BigIntegerField()
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'messages'

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.text)


class Number(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey("Message", related_name='receivers')
    number = models.BigIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "ReceiverNumber"
        verbose_name_plural = "ReceiverNumbers"
        managed = False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number
```

admin.py

```
class NumberInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Number
    extra = 0
    fields = ('number',)


class NumberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Meta:
        model = Number


class MessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ReceiverNumberInline,)

    class Meta:
        model = Message
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I completely understand the question, but have you tried overriding `save` method of `Number` model?

```
class Number(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey("Message", related_name='receivers')
    number = models.BigIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "ReceiverNumber"
        verbose_name_plural = "ReceiverNumbers"
        managed = False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do whatever you need without invoking super().save()
```

Comment: Kirill thank you for answer. It's not important anymore.